# Definition of nonvanishing $n$-form?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a $n$-manifold. I saw a theorem that a manifold $M$ is orientable iff there exists a smooth nonvanishing $n$-form $\omega$ on $M$. However, I am confused about the definition of nonvanishing; okay, it would mean that $\omega(v_1, \cdots, v_n) \neq 0$ for every $(v_1, \cdots, v_n)\in (T_*M)^n$, but does it include the case when $(v_1, \cdots, v_n)$ is linearly dependent set of vectors?

Comment: It means that at each point $x$, there is a tuple $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of vectors of $T_xM$ such that $\omega_x(v_1,\ldots,v_n) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Mindlack oh, so for each $x \in M$, showing existence of some $n$-tuple $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ satisfying $w_x(v_1, \cdots, v_n) \neq 0$ is sufficient? Just to confirm.

Comment: Non-vanishing means that at each $x$, $\omega_x$ is not a zero differential form of degree $n$ on $T_xM$. This does not mean that $\omega_x(v_1,\ldots,v_n) \neq 0$ for all vectors $v_i \in T_xM$, but that there exist some vectors such that it is not zero.

Comment: @James Chung: yes, that’s it.